# How to store stdin.lock() guard inside struct

Tags: rust, lifetime

Here I have a working example. I take a new `stdin` handle in main. I pass it to the function parse_something. In this function `stdin.lock()` returns a lockguard which I store into a struct that is finally returned. Picture the struct being some sort of iterator. And I would like this iterator to keep `stdin` locked as long as it is live. So far so good. The lockguard is linked to the lifetime `'a`. Which started at the new `stdin` handle in main.

```
use std::io::BufRead;

struct SomeIterator<B: BufRead> {
    buffer: B,
}

fn parse_something<'a>(stdin: &'a std::io::Stdin) -> SomeIterator<std::io::StdinLock<'a>> {
    let r = SomeIterator {
        buffer: stdin.lock(),
    };
    r
}

fn main() {
    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    parse_something(&stdin);
}
```

Let's now try to move the `stdin` handle instantiation inside the `parse_something` function.

```
use std::io::BufRead;

struct SomeIterator<B: BufRead> {
    buffer: B,
}

fn parse_something<'a>() -> SomeIterator<std::io::StdinLock<'a>> {
    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    let r = SomeIterator {
        buffer: stdin.lock(),
    };
    r
}

fn main() {
    parse_something();
}
```

I get the error `` error[E0597]: `stdin` does not live long enough ``. So far so good. stdin must live as long as `'a`. And for that, I should probably store the stdin handler inside `SomeIterator`.

The catch is I also must take a `.lock()` on the `stdin` handle with the same lifetime `'a`. I cannot figure out how.

This doesn't work because the lockguard references the `let stdin` variable, not on the (eventually moved) `stdin` attribute within `SomeIterator`.

```
struct SomeIterator<B: BufRead> {
    stdin: std::io::Stdin,
    buffer: B,
}

fn parse_something<'a>() -> SomeIterator<std::io::StdinLock<'a>> {
    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    let guard = stdin.lock();
    let r = SomeIterator {
        stdin: stdin,
        buffer: guard,
    };
    r
}
```

Eventually, I went all in, and added some random crap in the hope that perhaps I get lucky and stumble on the solution. No luck though. Here, I put `stdin` in a box. Technically, the content of the box should never be moving around in memory. Only the box "pointer object" is. I would hope that `r.stdin.lock()` actually uses the lifetime of the content within the Box. Which should be `'a` since the Box is part of `SomeIterator` which itself is generic over `'a`.

Sadly everything goes to shit when `r.stdin.lock()` actually borrows `r.stdin` before calling `.lock()`. This borrow only last for the scope of the function. `` `*r.stdin` does not live long enough `` hits hard.

```
struct SomeIterator<'a, B: BufRead + 'a> {
    stdin: Box<std::io::Stdin>,
    buffer: Option<B>,
    _marker: std::marker::PhantomData<&'a B>,
}

fn parse_something<'a>() -> SomeIterator<'a, std::io::StdinLock<'a>> {
    let mut r = SomeIterator {
        stdin: Box::new(std::io::stdin()),
        buffer: None,
        _marker: std::marker::PhantomData{},
    };
    r.buffer = Some(r.stdin.lock());
    r
}
```

I suspect that after weeding out the details, my question ultimately becomes: is it possible in safe Rust to store a reference to a sibling attribute? But I could be wrong.